# Why is my new refrigerator hot on the sides?

Tags: refrigerator

Today I received my new French door Hisense refrigerator, and I plugged in after cleaned up and it is very hot side to side (both side) is it normal to be hot first time?

Comment: Check your manual - most refrigerators should sit for 24 hours after moving before you plug them in, particularly if they were not kept vertical at all times when being moved.

Comment: Also, make sure there's enough air space around it. The sides might be hot because hot air can't get away from the refrigerator.

Comment: Is your fridge operating normally now?

Comment: Are the sides of the frige exposed, or against walls?

Answer (score 3):

The condensing coils in some refrigerators is under the skin of the unit. The heat is transferred to the living space. The harder the fridge is working the warmer to hot depending on how hard the system is working or trying to cool the interior food space.

Comment: I am not sure any fridge should be so hot that you notice it that much.  Mine are in the back and I can touch them.  They are a tiny warm but not hot.

Comment: DMoore, that's probably because your fridge was already cold. If you let it heat up, it has to get rid of that heat somehow